# Using JavaScript Variables On Different Files

Tags: javascript, html

I have a js variable defined in a js file like so :

onlineUsers.js :

```
var _onlineUsers=new Array();
```

I'm then linking the js file into index.html like so

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="onlineUsersVars.js"></script>
```

and I know for sure it gets a value after awhile since I've checked it with alert .

However , when I try to do the same with another html file , e.g file2.html 
then link the js file to get the same variable
file2.html :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="onlineUsersVars.js"></script>
```

and check the value , the value is nothing .

Anyone has a clue what I'm missing ? Do javascript variables 'die' after being linked to one page ? How can I share the same global javascript variable between many html pages ?

Comment: Javascript variables can be loaded in one file and used in another.  So it boils down to how you are doing it.  Perhaps you should post some code.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to include the script (`onlineUsers.js`) on every HTML page.  And the variable (`_onlineUsers`) will need to be re-instantiated on every HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah if you go from file1.html to file2.html, even though you have the same JS file on both files, the values will all clear. The best way to pass variables from page to page would be by using cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Try using HTML5 localStorage to store the variable and then call it each time you need to.

```
function onlineUsers() {
   var _onlineUsers=new Array();
   localStorage.onlineUsers = _onlineUsers;
}
```

Then this value will be available anytime you need it. Although that is client side not server side.

Comment: Thanks everybody - so you're saying the values clear between pages . As for HTML5 localStorage - how well will browsers support this do u think ?

Comment: wikipedia has an excellent article about this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML_5%29#APIs